# How to create a three-column responsive layout with icons and text?

Tags: html, css

I tried creating a three-column layout like below (click on the image to see it larger) :

[image]

It's basically an unordered list. I used `display: flex` on the `ul` element and FontAwesome to display those icons.

```
ul class="goals-list">
      <li><i class="fas fa-sun goals-icon"></i>Development of wind and solar power for the community. </li>
      ...
      ...
      ...
</ul>
```

As you can see the columns don't align well. The second column "Paving the community's roads", "Free Wifi", and "Doctors without borders visits" don't align at the same level.

I need a layout that aligns like a grid:

```
      item1          item2          item3
      item4          item5          item6
```

As the screen size is getting smaller I want them to wrap and automatically adjust like so:

```
      item1          item2
      item3          item4
      item5          item6
```

mobile portait:

```
      item1
      item2
      item3
      item4
      item5
      item6
```

I also want a little bit of space between the icons and the text. I would like to know how would you approach this problem. If you would be able to give me some ideas I would be grateful.

The problem is I don't know where to start. I'm not even sure if using an unordered list is the right way to approach this problem.

The reason I have three columns is because I have a `max-width: 1200px` set for the container and  that allows three columns to fit on the screen, but I think three columns look great on large 1920×1080 screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using below css:

```
.goals-list{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 33.33%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
    li{
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    li{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  li {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
  li {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css without using media queries.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
  flex: 1 0 400px;
}
```

The `400px` in the flex property sets that the element should be at least 400px (the actual property is *flex-basis*) this makes that if the available size is too small for 3 columns it will automatically make 2 columns of 500px (if the screen is 1000px).

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid layout and CSS variables.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.goals-list {
  --column-num: 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--column-num), 1fr);
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .goals-list {
    --column-num: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
  .goals-list {
    --column-num: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="goals-list">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice use of custom properties there too.